# Encountered this error anyone encountered before?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to prompt notification by pressing a button in Android Studio. I followed the tutorials on YouTube, but it gives a weird error saying I need permission.

I tried the solutions given by the IDE, but they didn’t help me. My code:

```
     Notification = findViewById(R.id.NotificationButton);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification", "My Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        Notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "My Notification");
                builder.setContentTitle("ALARM Notification")
                        .setContentText("PLease Take Your Phone")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_notifications_24)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
                managerCompat.notify(1, builder.build());
```

I am getting the error in the last row:

```
managerCompat.notify(1,builder.build());
```

Any advice on how to solve the error is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This method requires android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat#notify(int,android.app.Notification)

If you get this error exactly when this method is called then I would suspect you haven't included it in you manifest. See here for more details:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

This permission is needed since android 13, to declare it add it as follows:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```